# ASP.net Repeater: Best practice for nested layout

Tags: asp.net, html, nested-repeater

Basically, I'm asking for the best way to do the following:
I have a layout like this

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
    <div class="inner"><!-- content --></div>
</div>
```

So, the outer div is to be repeated three times, with each inner div repeated four times.  I'm doing this in ASP.net, the information is coming from a database (probably through Linq)...

I am asking is it better to use a nested repeater and spoon feed each repeater four records at a time through a for/foreach loop, or output the outer divs as literals?

EDITED

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyOuterRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="outer">
        <asp:Repeater ID="MyInnerRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="inner">
                <!-- content -->
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Or just have one, with opening/ending literals at the top and bottom, making them visible only when needed?

EDIT: Does anybody have an example how it would be done^^^

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way to do it. Sure there are options which are better performing, but will create a mess when you have to add another nested element within your inner div. This is neat code, scalable, maintainable. Makes you wonder if that millisecond in run-time is worth the trouble..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Your repeater definition will not create resulting HTML that you also provided in your question. It should actually be:</s>

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyOuterRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="outer">
            <asp:Repeater ID="MyInnerRepeater" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="inner">
                    <!-- content -->
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Otherwise your `outer div` will only be rendered once and all `inner` `div`s will be contained in the same outer `div`.

### Nesting repeaters?

If your `inner` elements are dynamic depending on data, you should of course use nested repeaters, but if every `outer` will contain four `inner`, then I don't see any benefit in having nested repeaters. It will actually execute slower and consume more resources. And that's something you don't want, do you?